# Problems with SSL: Unable to configure certificate for slaping

Tags: apache-2.4, domain, openssl, local-area-network, ubuntu-20.04

I have a self-hosted lubuntu server on my LAN which has some services useful for my net (a wordpress in /var/www/html, an owncloud, and a flask app). The problem is that some days ago I installed a self signed ssl certificate which worked perfectly but now I have the following error:

```
[Tue Nov 24 10:52:43.773996 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3684] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Nov 24 10:52:44.050510 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 3787] AH01906: miservidor.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Tue Nov 24 10:52:44.051147 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 3787] AH02217: ssl_stapling_init_cert: can't retrieve issuer certificate! [subject: emailAddress=example@example.com,CN=miservidor.com,OU=G5fighter IT,O=G5fighter Inc,L=Madrid,ST=Madrid,C=ES / issuer: emailAddress=example@example.com,CN=miservidor.com,OU=G5fighter IT,O=G5fighter Inc,L=Madrid,ST=Madrid,C=ES / serial: 54E9B9F567EDAB3274DD84A4A9ADE65D9A040B9F / notbefore: Nov 23 17:47:08 2020 GMT / notafter: Nov 23 17:47:08 2021 GMT]
[Tue Nov 24 10:52:44.051183 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 3787] AH02604: Unable to configure certificate miservidor.com:443:0 for stapling
[Tue Nov 24 10:52:44.156461 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 3798] AH01906: miservidor.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Tue Nov 24 10:52:44.157050 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 3798] AH02217: ssl_stapling_init_cert: can't retrieve issuer certificate! [subject: emailAddress=example@example.com,CN=miservidor.com,OU=G5fighter IT,O=G5fighter Inc,L=Madrid,ST=Madrid,C=ES / issuer: emailAddress=example@example.com,CN=miservidor.com,OU=G5fighter IT,O=G5fighter Inc,L=Madrid,ST=Madrid,C=ES / serial: 54E9B9F567EDAB3274DD84A4A9ADE65D9A040B9F / notbefore: Nov 23 17:47:08 2020 GMT / notafter: Nov 23 17:47:08 2021 GMT]
[Tue Nov 24 10:52:44.157086 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 3798] AH02604: Unable to configure certificate miservidor.com:443:0 for stapling
[Tue Nov 24 10:52:44.191002 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3798] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1g mod_wsgi/4.6.8 Python/2.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Nov 24 10:52:44.191095 2020] [core:notice] [pid 3798] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

These are my config files:

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName www.miservidor.com
        Redirect / https://miservidor.com/

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerName miservidor.com
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html
                ServerAlias www.miservidor.com
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key
                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>
           <Directory /var/www>
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
           </Directory>

        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I can acces to my server without problem directly with my IP but not with the domain. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**[UPDATE]**
After adding to my default-ssl.conf the following line:

```
SSLUseStapling off
```

It solves that error:

```
[Tue Nov 24 17:06:00.072579 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8938] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Nov 24 17:06:00.334836 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 9005] AH01906: miservidor.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Tue Nov 24 17:06:00.461929 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 9019] AH01906: miservidor.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Tue Nov 24 17:06:00.507795 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9019] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1g mod_wsgi/4.6.8 Python/2.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Nov 24 17:06:00.516896 2020] [core:notice] [pid 9019] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have OCSP stapling enabled.

Check the rest of your apache config for the [`SSLUseStapling`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslusestapling) directive and disable it if it is enabled.

Comment: How i do that??

Comment: Do what? Open a configuration file in a text editor?

Comment: I don't know what I have to change exactlt, can you explain it like to a noob(me)??

Comment: Well, you look for the directive and if it is set to `On` you change it to `Off`. I don't know what else you need.

Comment: I've beeins searching in my config files and i don't have that parameter, should i add it to default-ssl.conf?

Comment: Ok, I have added  SSLUseStapling off on my default-ssl.conf and I still get the same error

Comment: Hi @geraldschneider do you know how to continue now?

Comment: There are no errors in your logs after making that change. What exactly is the "error" you encounter? Is Apache not working, or do you only worry about the messages in the log files?

Comment: The problem is that even if i do that when I try to access to my server the browser says me, that the server has spent to much time to response, thats the reason why i'm trying to avoid that error, becouse in previous configurations of the server i didn't have that error.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more information, it's unreadable in the comments.

Comment: But i think that i will make another question and mark your answer as good, becouse you solved part of my problem.